# Passing XML Parser features to Saxon for stylesheet parsing

Tags: java, saxon

In the Saxon API, it is possible to pass XML parser features to the Configuration object using the `XML_PARSER_FEATURE` Config feature.

But it seems this is only applied to the parsing of the source document, and not of the XSLT stylesheet. Is there a way to configure stylesheet parsing as well, other than plugging in a custom parser?

Concretely, I need to make sure external entities are disabled for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that if you don't trust the stylesheet, there are many, many ways it can do damage other than using external entities. So disabling external entities is only one of the steps you need to take: the most important of which is to disable use of reflexive extension functions.

The best way to configure the parser for processing stylesheet modules is to create it yourself. For the main stylesheet module, supply a `SAXSource` containing an `XMLReader` configured the way you want it. For included and imported modules, use a `URIResolver` that allocates an `XMLReader` and returns a `SAXSource`.

There's also a configuration option `Feature.STYLE_PARSER_CLASS`. You can use this to implement your own class that implements the `XMLReader` interface, delegating the actual parsing to a "real" `XMLReader` over which you have full control.